# Regular polygons with equal height

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

Sorry for my naivety I am trying to plot the points of n sided regular polygons but maintaining the height between odd and even sided polygons.

Is there a sensible algorithm for doing so before I venture forward with a naive one?

Hopefully something visual will help elucidate the problem: 
https://youtu.be/OXVZjDUAA4c

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "height" of a polygon?

Comment: I guess I mean the radius/ diameter but on closer inspection perhaps that is folly. 

I will add an image for clarity

Comment: I assume you want all of them inscribed in a circle of a given radius. If this is the case, you simply divide circle into $n$ sectors and your vertices will be on the circle.

Comment: I thought that that is what I was doing when I calculate the x and y pos like this Sorry for the notation format (software engineer not mathematician):

x = sin(theta) * radius
y = cos(theta) * radius

Comment: With $\theta =2\pi k/n $?

Comment: I think thats doing the same thing. Thank you for your help. I have just done it a computationally/ cognitively lazy way. i.e. just working out the difference in the y axis and scaling the view by that amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The height of an $n$-gon (with $n$ odd) is
$$
\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)\cdot r.
$$
The height of an $n$-gon (with $n$-even) is 
$$
2r.
$$
So you can get the same height by scaling the size appropriatly.

Comment: Thats the one. Thank you so much for your help.